# How to implement a timeline in R with start date, end date, and a marker for a "middle date"?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, timeline

We have a data frame in `R` of the following format:

```
Type    Request ID  Event Name  First Seen           Update       Last Seen
A          1          Event1    1/29/2017 19:54 4/19/2017 14:16 4/19/2017 15:05        
A          2          Event2    2/13/2017 14:20 5/2/2017 12:48  5/2/2017 12:54
A          3          Event3    4/29/2017 16:30 5/12/2017 11:05 5/12/2017 12:08
B          4          Event4    5/17/2017 20:23 5/18/2017 12:46 5/18/2017 16:15
```

The corresponding CSV file is:

```
Type,Request ID,Event Name,First Seen,Update,Last Seen
A,1,Event1,1/29/2017 19:54,4/19/2017 14:16,4/19/2017 15:05
A,2,Event2,2/13/2017 14:20,5/2/2017 12:48,5/2/2017 12:54
A,3,Event3,4/29/2017 16:30,5/12/2017 11:05,5/12/2017 12:08
B,4,Event4,5/17/2017 20:23,5/18/2017 12:46,5/18/2017 16:15
```

We want to visualize each instance on an R timeline such that we can see the Event on a timeline with start date, update, and end date.

We were able to get very close to this with our implementation in R which goes like this:

```
install.packages("timevis")
library("timevis")

df <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE)
df_new = rename(df, start = First.Seen, end = Last.Seen, content = Request.ID)
timevis(dataframe_new)
```

Note that we are only using 'start' date and 'end' date in this implementation. This plots the following timeline:

[image]

Now we want to incorporate the 'Update' date and time in there somehow such that we are shown a pointer in each bar or slab indicating the update date and time. The bar will start at start date, end at end date, and have a marker at appropriate location to show the 'Update'.

How can we implement this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your data

```
df <- structure(list(Type = c("A", "A", "A", "B"), Request.ID = 1:4, 
Event.Name = c("Event1", "Event2", "Event3", "Event4"), First.Seen = structure(c(1485719640, 
1486995600, 1493483400, 1495052580), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Update = structure(c(1492611360, 1493729280, 
1494587100, 1495111560), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Last.Seen = structure(c(1492614300, 1493729640, 
1494590880, 1495124100), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Type", "Request.ID", 
"Event.Name", "First.Seen", "Update", "Last.Seen"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

#### tidyverse solution

I `melt` `First.Seen` & `Update` into a single column. The `Last.Seen` values for each `Update` value is `= NA` (made into a singularity). I add `type` column specifying `point` for singularities and `background` for ranges (to overlap values). I also add a `group` value.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(lubridate)
df1 <- df %>% 
         nest(First.Seen, Update) %>% 
         mutate(data = map(data, ~melt(.x))) %>% 
         unnest() %>%
         mutate(Last.Seen = ifelse(variable == "Update", as.character(NA), as.character(Last.Seen))) %>%
         mutate(Last.Seen = ymd_hms(Last.Seen)) %>%
         mutate(type = ifelse(is.na(Last.Seen), "point", "background")) %>%
         mutate(group = Request.ID) %>%
         rename(start = value, end = Last.Seen, content = Request.ID)
```

First 4 rows of `df1`

```
   Type content Event.Name                 end   variable               start       type group
1     A       1     Event1 2017-04-19 15:05:00 First.Seen 2017-01-29 19:54:00 background     1
2     A       1     Event1                  NA     Update 2017-04-19 14:16:00      point     1
3     A       2     Event2 2017-05-02 12:54:00 First.Seen 2017-02-13 14:20:00 background     2
4     A       2     Event2                  NA     Update 2017-05-02 12:48:00      point     2
```

Specify groups and what to label each row with `groups=...`

```
timevis(data=df1, groups=data.frame(id=unique(df1$group), content=LETTERS[unique(df1$content)]))
```

This produces four rows of timelines with the `Update` singularity (point) marking each range of `First.Seen` & `Last.Seen`.

Comment: I loaded all relevant libraries required for these functions, but executing the first part `df1 <- ...` gives me this error: `Using  as id variables
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: names do not match previous names.`

Comment: Sorry about not specifying the libraries. Bad habit of mine. I've indicated which libraries are required. Could you double check that you've loaded the same libraries? Just double checking...are you using `df` or your own data?

Comment: Thank you. I was using `reshape` instead of `reshape2` and `tidyv` instead of `tidyverse`. So it does compile after loading the right libraries. It does plot the timeline but with an issue: the four rows of timelines are labeled `A B C D` when according to data it should be `A A A B`

Comment: Try this then `timevis(data=df1, groups=data.frame(id=df$Request.ID, content=df$Type))` Notice that it grabs the data from the original data frame `df` as well.